# Cancel system navigation in a Web Context UWP app

Tags: uwp, tile

my app is suspended and i click on the pinned main tile or on the all-apps list item and open the app again, now my app resumes very fast and the last state is shown. But after some milliseconds the complete single page application is reloading. 
How can i cancel or avoid this navigation event that is triggered by the system that causes this reload?

Comment: Have you register the resuming event handler in your page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have give this scenario a test and it seems it is related to this problem:

```
ms-appx-web:///index.html
```

If we use **index.html** then we won't have this problem. So the expected behavior from your last past matches your idea.

However since the project seems do not use the local index.html, the **ms-appx-web:///index.html** page's behavior is more likely to be a web page behavior and it will have the navigation, maybe that is a expected behavior.